# Opencv3 Camera Release doesn't work with PyQt5

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5, opencv3.0

I am using opencv3 to capture an image using my webcam. Then I display the image to label using PyQt5. Here is my code below. the problem I am having here is that the camera won't disengage after the image is capture. I have to close the program/stop script manually for the camera light to go off. Am I missing something? Where is the gap in my knowledge? How can i fix this?

```
class View_image(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = view_image_dialog.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        if cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
        else:
            ret = False
        cap.release()

        image_Qt=QImage(frame,frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],QImage.Format_RGB888)
        imgswap = image_Qt.rgbSwapped()
        self.ui.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(imgswap))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    c = View_image()
    c.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can captures images, but after I capture the image, the camera does not disengage. I can keep capturing images and display to label, but I get an error/warning in the shell as follows:

```
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
```

I am using opencv3, Windows 10 64-bit, PyQt5 5.11.2

Comment: I tested your script with my laptop's webcam and it works correctly, have you tried with another camera? Have you tried on another PC?

Comment: What warning???

Comment: it works, but the problem is the camera does not release unless I close the running program. I can keep taking pictures but I get this warning in the shell [ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821

Comment: That information is important, you must place it as an edition of your question.

Comment: it would be good to indicate the version of opencv that you use (it is specified), the version of PyQt5 and what is your OS.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, as you can tell i'm a noob, I appreciate your help with this! I have updated per your requests..